# Estrutura dos assemblies em um projeto utilizando o pattern MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Estou tendo dificuldades em organizar a solution de um projeto utilizando o pattern MVVM. Não utilizo nenhum framework MVVM.

Atualmente tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
Solution
    |
    --- AppView (Projeto principal onde estão as views e que é iniciado pelo App.xaml)
    |
    --- AppViewModel (Assembly que contém as viewmodels)
    |
    --- AppModel (Assembly que contém os modelos de dados - Pessoa.cs, Cliente.cs, etc...)
```

As referências são:

`AppView -> AppViewModel -> AppModel`

Ao iniciar a aplicação é apresentado a `AppView.MainWindow`. Esta possui o `viewmodel` - `AppViewModel.MainWindowViewModel` (em assembly separado).

A dificuldade surgiu quando preciso que esta `viewmodel` abra outra `Window`, visto que não consigo fazer isso no assembly `AppViewModel`, devido às referências.

Portanto, gostaria de saber se alguém tem um exemplo do `pattern MVVM` com uma estrutura em que os assemblies de `view` e `viewmodel` são distintos.

Comment: Se "abre window" é "navega para janela", isso pode ser feito com um serviço de navegação implementado à semelnaça do que o @Cigano Morrison Mem sugeriu.

Comment: Recomendo este guia: http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso se faz por callbacks e delegates, que é um objeto de função chamável. Em algum momento você terá que preencher este objeto de função ao instanciar sua classe `ViewModel`. Acho que o jeito mais correto é por interfaces. Você pode fazer algo assim:

Interface:

```cs
public interface IObjeto
{
    void MeuMetodo();
}
```

Objeto da AppView:

```cs
public class Objeto: IObjeto
{
    public void MeuMetodo()
    {
        // Faz alguma coisa, como chamar a janela, por exemplo.
    }
}
```

Classe do ViewModel:

```cs
public class ClasseDoViewModel
{
    private IObjeto _objetoDoCallback;

    public ClasseDoViewModel(IObjeto objetoDoCallback) 
    {
        _objetoDoCallback = objetoDoCallback;
    } 

    public static void ChamarJanela(IObjeto objetoDoCallback)
    {
        objetoDoCallback.MeuMetodo();
    }
}
```

Você pode inclusive estender esse padrão pro seu `AppModel`.